# How do I install hardhat so that can avoid error?

Tags: blockchain, hardhat

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQxRp.png)
I tried installing hardhat from the terminal but got 'a complete log of this item can not be found'

Comment: try using 

```npm install --save-dev hardhat@2.8.4``` 

replace version no. if wanted

Answer (score 0):

The following blog might help -
https://meetjainblogs.hashnode.dev/hardhat

It contains content from testing to deployment.